# AJAX upload big file not work

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, form-data

I am developing MVC application. I want to upload file with ajax post method,

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Add", "Media")',
            data: formData,

            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                if (result.Status !== 200) {

                    toastr.error('@Resources.Resource.Error_Unexpected');
                    return;
                }

                if (result.Result === "SUCCEED") {
                    toastr.success('@Resources.Resource.SuccessUpload');
                    window.location.reload();



                    return;
                } else {
                    toastr.error('@Resources.Resource.Error_Unexpected');
                }

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                toastr.error('@Resources.Resource.Error_Unexpected');
                return;
            }
        });
    }
```

It works with small file. But when I try to upload 90MB pdf file it doesn't goes to controller. What is the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your web.config file you need to increase maximum upload file setting. It affects the entire application.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxx" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You need to place value in KB. The default is 4096 (= 4 MB).